# handleChange is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, eslint

I am trying to use the handleChange funtion in react but it keeps telling me undefined. This is my code.

```
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, handleChange }) => (
  <input
    placeholder={placeholder}
    type={type}
    step='0.0001'
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, name)}
    className='my-2 w-full rounded-sm p-2 outline-none bg-transparent text-white border-none text-sm  white-glassmorphism'
  />
);
```

I tried everything but to no avail

Comment: Where are you calling the `Input` component?

Comment: <Input placeholder="Address To" name="addressTo" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Amount (ETH)" name="amount" type="number" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Keyword (Gif)" name="keyword" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Enter Message" name="message" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />

Comment: It seems that you might not be passing `handleChange` from parent component. `Input` seems to be O.K.

Comment: O.K, so the `handleChange` prop is being "drilled" multiple levels. Where it is being created (defined)?

Comment: HynekS, I thought passing it in as a parameter of onChange creates the handleChange

Comment: if I am wrong could you assist me on where to create the handleChange

Comment: You need to declare a function `handleChange` to handle input changes. The function might, e.g., update a state with a new value, but it vastly differs regarding the form implementation (and libraries you might use).

Answer (score 0):

Ebenezer Kissiedu, you have to explicitly define the handlechange handler in the App.js component & pass it as a prop where you want to render the `<Input />` Component. I have fixed & created a solution - [handleChange() fixed](https://codesandbox.io/s/76090301-handlechange-not-defined-k09vjt) - please visit this snippet in codesandbox.

```js
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, handleChange }) => (
  <input
    placeholder={placeholder}
    type={type}
    step="0.0001"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, name)}
    className="my-2 w-full rounded-sm p-2 outline-none bg-transparent text-white border-none text-sm  white-glassmorphism"/>
);

const handleChange = (event, name) => {
  console.log("value:" + event.target.value);
  console.log("name:" + name);
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Input placeholder="Hello" name="my-input" handleChange={handleChange} />
  );
}
```